# Access extended class' properties and methods with TypeScript decorators

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, decorator

I'm working on an experimental refactoring of my express app and chose to go with TypeScript as I prefer strong typing with any language. I saw the potential of using TypeScript's decorators as a powerful method to build a well-structured project as DRY as possible.

I'm having issues in accessing a property from a class that is extended by a class where I have the decorator set up.

example:

```
class BaseRouter {

    app: express.Application = express;

    // some other common stuff
}

function PostMethod(route: string = '/') {

    return (target: BaseRouter, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {

        // This is where things don't work out
        // descriptor.value correctly returns the RequestHandler which I can attach to express
        // target.app is undefined
        target.app.post(route, descriptor.value);
    }
}
```

router.ts

```
@ResourceRouter() // <= this is optional, can I access all decorators inside the class from this decorator? That would also lead me to a solution
export class BlogRouter extends BaseRouter {


    @GetMethod()
    index(req, res) {

        // req.send(...); return posts
    }


    @GetMethod('/:modelId')
    show(req, res, next) {

         // find req.params.modelId
    }

    @PostMethod()
    createPost() {}

    @DeleteMethod()
    deletePost() {}

    @UpdateMethod()
    updatePost() {}
}
```

I know this is not perfect I'm just experimenting with decorators at the moment as I have successfully used them in other scenarios that works really well. Note that this is not in any way Angular 2+ related.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @torazaburo In the first example inside the return statement(`PostMethod`) I am not able to access `app` property from within the decorator. Is there a way I could access `app` from `BaseRouter`?

Comment: Your property is not a static property, it's an instance property. I think you should write a method decorator there that can access `this` of an object.

Comment: how does the method decorator access `this`?